# Using library file built by different IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ide, clion

I'm trying to use [KDL](http://www.orocos.org/kdl).

KDL is a library for computing kinematics and dynamics of robot maniputlator.

I built KDL with `Visual Studio 2010`.

I got `orocos-kdl.lib` successfully.

And I can use this library file in `VS2010` but cannot use it in another IDE(`CLion`) with this error `undefined reference to ...`.

But the same code can be built in `VS2010`.

> A library file, built by different IDE, cannot be used?

If I built it by `VS2010`, I can use it only in `VS2010`?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

> Object files and static libraries created with different compilers, or even with significantly different releases of the same compiler, often cannot be linked together.

visit [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands).